# How to scale and change the origin of parent view and implement in subviews too?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I want to create a menu view which hides and unhides on button press. Now I managed to do it to the parent view but the buttons which are subview of the menuview are not scaling accordingly what i need to do? Here's the code!

```
menuInitFrame=menuView.frame;
newFrame=CGRectMake(320, 0, 0, 0);
```

Storing the initial state and new state;

```
if (menuView.hidden==NO) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay: 0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         menuView.frame = newFrame;   // move
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         menuView.hidden=YES;
     }];
}
else if(menuView.hidden==YES)
{
    menuView.hidden=NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay: 0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         menuView.frame = menuInitFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         //menuViewStatus=NO;
     }];
}
```

Comment: How is the buttons laid out inside the menuView? Do you use autolayout or manually set their frames too?

Comment: I used autolayout. And placed the button inside menu view through the interface builder.

Comment: Then after setting a new frame you should call [menuView layoutIfNeeded]

Comment: And what inside layoutIfneeded?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using auto-layout you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` to recalculate frames of all subviews inside your menuView.

So inside your animation block add the following line:

```
menuView.frame = menuInitFrame;
[menuView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: That is changing the scale of menuView in unexpected way! And also subviews are not being scaled.

Comment: Then you need to provide a code/screenshot of how your auto-layout is set.